# Order by time starting at?

Tags: mysql, time, sql-order-by

You can easily order by time in MYSQL, for example

```
"SELECT * from table WHERE date = 2012-04-29 order by time"
```

MYSQL will then order by the time starting with 00:00:00

My question is it possible to tell MYSQL to starting at say 06:00:00 instead of the default.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't storing date and time in the same field? Your where statement would then become: WHERE datetime_field > '2012-04-29 06:00:00' order by datetime_field

Comment: So, the rows with time between `00:00` and `06:00` should not be shown? Or shown at the end?

Comment: Year shown at the end as you put. Lynn's comment and SoEnlion answer both suggest I should do greater or less than operation. I don't want to do this. I simply want to control when the order by starts.

Comment: Lynn using a datetime field is not possible in my application as I need to have the date and time field in separate fields.

Comment: I think what you're asking is to be able to have 00:00:00 - 00:06:00 appear with the default order by, and have 00:06:00 and onward use the time order by. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE date = 2012-04-29
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN hour(time) < 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, time;
```

Stil, I find it more error prone to have date and time separated.

Comment: Excellent. Googled "ORDER BY CASE" found this http://www.extremeexperts.com/SQL/Articles/CASEinORDER.aspx which is pretty much what I was asking. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE date = 2012-04-29 
   AND TIME>= 06:00:00
ORDER BY time;
```